# Get Accession Numbers from NCBI from corresponding GI Numbers in fasta headers in python

Tags: python, fasta, ncbi, genbank

I keep seeing warnings on Genbank that they are phasing out GI numbers and have a number of fasta files saved where I've edited the headers in the following format:

```
>SomeText_ginumber
```

I've no idea where to even begin with this but is there a way, ideally with python, that I could get the corresponding accession numbers for each gi from NCBI and output a file with the headers as follows:

```
>SomeText_accessionnumber
```

Here's another example of the file format:

```
>Desulfovibrio_fructosivorans_ferredoxin_492837709
MTKSVAPTVTIDGKVVPIEGERNLLELIRKVRIDLPTFCYHSELSVYGACRLCLVEVKNRGIMGAC
>Oxalobacteraceae_bacterium_AB_14_hypothetical_protein_522195384
MIKLTVNGIPVEVDEGATYLDAANKAGVHIPTLCYHPRFRSHAVCRMCLVHVAGSSRPQAACIGKA
```

**Edit/Update:**

```
from Bio import Entrez
from time import sleep
import sys
import re
Entrez.email = ''

seqs = open(sys.argv[1],"r")

for line in seqs:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        gi = re.findall("\d{5,}",line)
        matches = len(gi)
        #print(matches)
        if matches < 2:
            if gi:
                handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=gi, retmode="xml")
                records = Entrez.read(handle)
                print(line[0:line.rfind('_') + 1] + records[0]['GBSeq_primary-accession'])
                sleep(1)
        elif matches >= 2:
             print("Error - More than one ginumber in header!")
             break
        else:
            seq=line.rstrip()
            print(seq)
    else:
        seq1=line.rstrip()
        print(seq1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [BioPython](https://github.com/biopython/biopython.github.io/).

The following snippet should get you started. First get the GI from the header (the part of the header after the underscore), get the data from GenBank, print the old header but with the accession number and then the rest of your input sequences, done :)

This works for your two examples but will probably fail with more data (missing GI, etc.). Also the accession numbers have underscores, just like your header, will will complicate parsing later. Perhaps replace the underscore with something else or add another separator.

```
from Bio import Entrez
from time import sleep
Entrez.email = 'your@email'

seqs = """>Desulfovibrio_fructosivorans_ferredoxin_492837709
MTKSVAPTVTIDGKVVPIEGERNLLELIRKVRIDLPTFCYHSELSVYGACRLCLVEVKNRGIMGAC
>Oxalobacteraceae_bacterium_AB_14_hypothetical_protein_522195384
MIKLTVNGIPVEVDEGATYLDAANKAGVHIPTLCYHPRFRSHAVCRMCLVHVAGSSRPQAACIGKA"""


for line in seqs.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('>'):
        gi = line[line.rfind('_') + 1:]
        handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=gi, retmode="xml")
        records = Entrez.read(handle)
        print(line[0:line.rfind('_') + 1] + records[0]['GBSeq_primary-accession'])
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print(line)
```

Comment: That's really helpful. I'd only just worked out how to retrieve the accessions from a comma delimited list of gi numbers so this helps a lot.

I was thinking of using a regular expression to get the ginumbers e.g. '[0-9]{4,}'. Then it perhaps wouldn't matter if there were some fasta entries with no ginumber?
I guess what [line.rfind('_') + 1:] does is take the string after the last instance of '_'?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. rfind finds the first occurrence from the right, i.e. the last occurence, of your search string.
If all your headers have identical formats, you could just loop over all the files and write the new header to a new file. Your regex approach could also work but I would first check if you get false positives. Also checking if the number of records is exactly 1 should be mandatory to avoid errors and assigning wrong accession numbers.

Comment: That's great, thank you. I've made the edits you suggest and updated the original post. I now have a nice useful script!
One final issue, is there a way to replace the gi number with the accession number, no matter where it is in the header? Currently if the GI number is at the beginning of the header for example, then it still puts the accession at the end of the line and removes what ever was after the last '_'

Comment: Actually, I've realised that this doesn't really matter for this script as all my headers are only in this format. Cheers!